# Difficulty constructing a controller with injected dependencies in Unity ASP.NET Web API

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, unity-container

I know there are similar questions for this out there, but I've spent hours trying to follow them to no avail so I would really appreciate some help.

I'm working on a simple ASP.NET MVC project, and I'm trying to inject dependencies into a Web API Controller with Unity. The basic structure is:

```
EmailController <- NotificationEngine <- EmailAccessor
```

EmailAccessor's constructor needs to have injected values from `Web.config` AppSettings. `EmailController` and `NotificationEngine` only take a single object in their constructors. Here's an abridged version of the code:

#### EmailAccessor

```
public class EmailAccessor : IEmailAccessor
{
    private string senderEmail;
    private string senderUsername;
    private string senderPassword;
    private int port;

    public EmailAccessor(string senderEmail, string senderUsername, string senderPassword, int port)
    {
        this.senderEmail = senderEmail;
        this.senderUsername = senderUsername;
        this.senderPassword = senderPassword;
        this.port = port;
    }
    //...
}
```

#### NotificationEngine

```
public class NotificationEngine : INotificationEngine
{
    private IEmailAccessor emailAccessor;

    public NotificationEngine(IEmailAccessor emailAccessor)
    {
        this.emailAccessor = emailAccessor;
    }
    //...
}
```

#### EmailController

```
[RoutePrefix("api/email")]
public class EmailController : ApiController
{
    private INotificationEngine notificationEngine;

    public EmailController(INotificationEngine notificationEngine)
    {
        this.notificationEngine = notificationEngine;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("send")]
    public void Post([FromBody] EmailNotification email)
    {
        //...
    }
    //...
}
```

#### UnityConfig

Finally, here's the class where I register my types

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.LoadConfiguration();

        //...

        container.RegisterType<IEmailAccessor, EmailAccessor>(new InjectionConstructor(
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderEmail"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderUsername"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderPassword"],
                int.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Port"])));
        container.RegisterType<INotificationEngine, NotificationEngine>();

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

    }
}
```

The settings are all pulled from `<appSettings>` in `Web.config`.

When I try and POST to `localhost:63855/api/email/send`, I get the following response:

```
{
    "Message": "No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'http://localhost:63855/api/email/send'.",
    "MessageDetail": "No type was found that matches the controller named 'email'."
}
```

Comment: Debug and watch out for *all* exceptions. If it is actually related to Unity you'll see some decent traces about what actually happening.

Comment: There are no exceptions thrown when I start my application.

Answer (score 1):

> I'm working on a simple ASP.NET MVC project, and I'm trying to inject dependencies into a Web API Controller

It is not a "simple ASP.NET MVC project". It is a hybrid project with both ASP.NET MVC and Web API in it, which are 2 separate frameworks. Each of these frameworks has its own types and its own configuration.

You have configured DI with ASP.NET MVC, but **not** with Web API. To use both frameworks with DI, you must set the Dependency Resolver for *both* frameworks in your project.

```
// MVC's DependencyResolver
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new UnityDependencyResolver(container));

// Web API's DependencyResolver
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver 
    = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);
```

This assumes that the `UnityDependencyResolver` you are using implements `System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver`. If not, there are instructions on how to build one at [Dependency Resolution with the Unity Container](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/dependency-injection).

Also, be sure you have enabled attribute routing, or none of your Web API attribute routes will be picked up by the framework. This method must be called at application startup.

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(config =>
{
    // ** Enable Attribute Routing for Web API **
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    // For the config you are showing, you don't necessarily need this
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
    );
});
```

If that doesn't solve it, there is [another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17811142/no-type-was-found-that-matches-the-controller-named-user) you should check out the answers for.

Comment: Adding `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new UnityDependencyResolver(container);` did not fix the issue. Also, the `UnityDependencyResolver` I am using comes built into `Unity.AspNet.WebApi`, and implements `IDependencyResolver`, among other things.

Comment: Since you were missing that step, I will leave it as part of the answer. But I have updated to include the solution to another potential problem and a link to another similar question.